# Sorting descending after calculating percentage in v-for

Tags: javascript, vue.js, sorting, vuejs3, v-for

In Vue.js for calculating percentage I have the following code:

```
  <tr>
    <span v-for="(item, index) in data.values" :key="index" >
      {{ item.name }} {{ getPercentage(item.nr) }}
    </span>
  </tr>
```

And in the percentage method:

```
methods: {
  getPercentage (number) {
    return number/ this.nrUsers * 100; (ignore the logic)
  }
}
```

The percentage values are calculated alright but the problem is when displaying them. I would like to have sorted descending and I don't think I can do it from BE because the percentage is calculated here. Any ideas how to do that in Vue.js?

Comment: Can yu explain what that means? `I would like to have sorted descending`

Comment: sorry, I meant I would like to have the items listed in descending order based on the percentage, cause at the moment it's displayed the way it comes from the db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create computed property instead of method:

```js
const app = Vue.createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      items: [{id: 1, nr: 5, name: 'aaa'}, {id: 5, nr: 15, name: 'bbb'}, {id: 2, nr: 7, name: 'ccc'}, {id: 3, nr: 24, name: 'ddd'}, {id: 4, nr: 25, name: 'eee'}],
    };
  },
  computed: {
    sortedItems() {
      return this.items.map(item => {
        let pct = item.nr / 100 * this.items.length;
        return { ...item, pct }
      }).sort((a, b) => b.nr - a.nr)
       
    }
  },
})
app.mount('#demo')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <li v-for="(item, index) in sortedItems" :key="index" >
      {{ item.name }} {{ item.pct }}
    </li>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't sort the items at the time of rendering. You first need to sort your data in descending order and then you can render.

According to your comment, you can surely sort the items first.

1. Fetch the data from API.
2. Loop over data items and calculate their percentage.
3. Sort the data in descending order according to the percentage value.
4. And last, render this sorted data in the template.

Hope this gives some direction.